# Poor performance on joining two large tables

Tags: mysql, performance, join, mariadb

I am struggling since several days with poor performance on joining two large tables. Maybe someone has a hint for me.

The one table is "broker_stock_data" which holds informations about purchases and sells of stocks of a client (this table is currently small but will grow bigger in future). To show the client the current price for his stocks there is the table "stock_data" which holds historical stock prices for a big amount of stocks (currently around 2million rows and growing). It´s a mariaDB/mysql Database and the table uses InnoDB.

Here are some informations about my tables:
broker_stock_data Table
[image]
stock_data Table
[image]
EXPLAIN Call on the SELECT
[image]
Schema of stock_data table
[image]

Having that in place I need to somehow get the latest price for each stock which is owned by a client. To do that I have the following query.

```
SELECT
   `brokerStockData`.`id` AS `id`,
   `brokerStockData`.`name` AS `name`,
   `brokerStockData`.`symbol` AS `symbol`,
   `brokerStockData`.`wkn` AS `wkn`,
   `brokerStockData`.`modifyDate` AS `modifyDate`,
   `brokerStockData`.`addDate` AS `addDate`,
   `webApiConfig`.`id` AS `webApiConfigId`,
   `webApiConfig`.`name` AS `webApiConfigName`,
   `importError`.`msg` AS `importErrorMessage`,
   SUM(`brokerStockData`.`purchaseAmount`) AS `purchaseAmount`,
   stockData.stock_data_close AS `stockDataClose`,
   stockData.stock_data_date AS `purchaseDate`,
   stockData.stock_data_close * SUM(purchaseAmount) - SUM(purchasePrice * purchaseAmount) / SUM(purchaseAmount) * SUM(purchaseAmount) AS `difference`,
   (
(stockData.stock_data_close * purchaseAmount - SUM(purchasePrice * purchaseAmount) / SUM(purchaseAmount) * purchaseAmount) / (SUM(purchasePrice * purchaseAmount) / SUM(purchaseAmount) * purchaseAmount) 
   )
   * 100 AS `yield`,
   SUM(purchasePrice * purchaseAmount) / SUM(purchaseAmount) AS `avgPurchasePrice` 
FROM
   `broker_stock_data` `brokerStockData` 
   INNER JOIN
      `broker` `broker` 
      ON `broker`.`id` = `brokerStockData`.`brokerId` 
   INNER JOIN
      `user` `user` 
      ON `user`.`id` = `broker`.`userId` 
   INNER JOIN
      `webapi_configuration` `webApiConfig` 
      ON `webApiConfig`.`id` = `brokerStockData`.`webApiConfigId` 
   LEFT JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            `stockData`.`date` AS `stock_data_date`,
            `stockData`.`symbol` AS `stock_data_symbol`,
            `stockData`.`close` AS `stock_data_close`,
            `stockData`.`webApiConfigId` AS `stock_data_webApiConfigId` 
         FROM
            `stock_data` `stockData` 
         WHERE
            `stockData`.`date` IN 
            (
               SELECT
                  MAX(`stockDataSQ`.`date`) 
               FROM
                  `stock_data` `stockDataSQ` 
               WHERE
                  `stockDataSQ`.`symbol` = `stockData`.`symbol` 
               GROUP BY
                  `stockDataSQ`.`symbol`
            )
         GROUP BY
            `stockData`.`symbol`
      )
      `stockData` 
      ON `brokerStockData`.`symbol` = stock_data_symbol 
      AND `webApiConfig`.`id` = stock_data_webApiConfigId 
   LEFT JOIN
      `import_log` `importError` 
      ON `importError`.`symbol` = `brokerStockData`.`symbol` 
WHERE
   `user`.`id` = 2 
   AND `broker`.`id` = 2 
   AND `brokerStockData`.`symbol` != "" 
GROUP BY
   `brokerStockData`.`symbol` 
ORDER BY
   `brokerStockData`.`name` ASC LIMIT 12
```

The problematic part is the LEFT JOIN on the stock_data table. Any Ideas on how to speed this up?

***UPDATE***
Changed the query since I copied a modified version of me :/

***UPDATE2***
Updated the EXPLAIN screenshot with the new query, sorry ;)

Comment: do you have some testdata plus the create tables or post the explain of your query

Comment: @BerndBuffen You can find the EXPLAIN call in the screenshots. I labelled them now to make it more clear. Do you still need Create calls and data then?

Comment: if you have data it is easyer for me to change the query.

Comment: I'm confused.  This seems to say that each user has many brokers??  ON `user`.`id` = `broker`.`userId`

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... )` is likely to be very inefficient.  Can you get rid of the `LEFT`?

Because of the `LIMIT 12`, a common trick to improve performance is to do the minimum work to find the 12 ids *first*.  *Then* do whatever `JOINs` are needed to find all the other data.

After you have done that, I'll look at the indexes.

```
GROUP BY
   `brokerStockData`.`symbol` 
ORDER BY
   `brokerStockData`.`name` ASC
```

Because the lists are different, it requires sorting twice.  Change to this:

```
GROUP BY
   `brokerStockData`.`name`,     `brokerStockData`.`symbol` 
ORDER BY
   `brokerStockData`.`name` ASC, `brokerStockData`.`symbol` ASC
```

Assuming `symbol` and `name` are 1:1, you will get same results, but faster.